# How do I compile bitcoin core to be more portable?

Tags: gnu-make, bitcoind

Background: I compile bitcoind on one system but run it on another. When I compiled bitcoind 0.19.1 some time back using the following method, I was able to run bitcoind and bitcoin-cli on the target system without issue. *I think*.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-wallet --disable-tests --disable-bench --disable-gui --enable-util-tx=no --prefix=$HOME/bitcoind/x64 --exec-prefix=$HOME/bitcoind/x64
make && make install
```

Today I compiled v0.20.0 using the same method. If I run ./bitcoind -version on the system I compiled the binary it runs fine, but if I take the binary to my target system I get the following error:

```
./bitcoind: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The binary seemed to be portable last time, and the pre-compiled binary I download from the Bitcoin Core team runs fine.

Note that on the target system `libboost-filesystem-dev` and `libboost-filesystem1.67-dev` are not installed, this is likely the source of my error. That said, running the pre-compiled binary from the Core team runs, so why doesn't mine?

Can someone help me understand if I did something wrong or if I need to add ./configure flags to make the binary more portable? Specifically what I likely did differently than the core developers that made my binary fail where theirs worked?

EDIT 1: Running `./configure --enable-static` or `./configure LDFLAGS=-static` does not result in a portable binary either.

Also note that installing libboost-filesystem library with apt does fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew Chow for his helpful answer to this on the bitcoind StackExchange. I needed to build the depends as per the [depends documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/depends/README.md). Since I'm building for the same platform I'll be running on, I can run make in the depends directory with no arguments except -j2 which uses two cores. Change the number to however many cores you want to commit to the compile.

```
cd depends
make -j2
cd ..
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=$PWD/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
make -j2 && make install
```